# Regex multiline match only if string does not contain A but contains B

Tags: regex

Match a multi-line string that does not contain A in one line, but contains B in another line.

The hard part is that the file contain multiple of these multi-line constructs.

The easy part is that the regex should only return true / false (found / not found) if the file contains an invalid group.

In my example, I should match a `story(...)` only if it contains `bar`, but does not contain `foo`. `stuff..` is optional and it can be 0 or many lines of random words.

Example of a bad file:

```
story(
  stuff..,
  foo,
  stuff..,
  bar,
)

story(
  stuff..,
  bar,
)         // <-- this file is bad because of this story
```

Example of a good file:

```
story(
  stuff..,
  foo,
  stuff..,
  bar,
)

story(
  stuff..,
  foo,
  stuff..,
  bar,
)

// no matches found here, the file is good
```

Is it even possible to do this with regex? If it is, it should work here: https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html

Comment: Please tag the desired language

Comment: @FailSafe I could parse this in any Turing complete language. But I need it as a regex rule.

Comment: which version of regex?

Comment: your example bad story doesn't contain foo and does contain bar so shouldn't match according to your specification

Comment: Here's kind of a dirty solution for Python `re.findall('story[\S\s]*?foo=bar[\S\s]*?qwe=raz[\S\s]*?\)|(story[\S\s]*?\))', string)`

Comment: If you save your text to a string, it returns a list where if foo=bar exists, the result will be blank, but if it doesn't it will show what the query is. Actually, you stipulated that `qwe=raz` HAD to be inside of it?

Comment: @jhnc Fixed the description. We are using google's https://github.com/google/re2 in our project.

Comment: @FailSafe I simplified my example.

Comment: Ok. Will take a look. What I had above should do what was needed before though. You can just search the resulting array to see if any values were NOT `''`, in which case it would be a bad file

Comment: Looking at what's not supported in [RE2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), I'm not sure it's powerful enough

Comment: So: ok = (has foo, has bar) or (has foo) or (no foo, no bar); bad = (no foo, has bar) ? In either case, you need a regex engine that can match "doesn't contain X". I don't think RE2 can.

Comment: @jhnc That's correct.

Comment: Check below answer. See if that works

Comment: @FailSafe I tested only the regex for both examples on regex101.com and it matches both of them. Whereas it should match only a bad file, and only because of the second example in the bad file. What I see is that the group is correctly picked up. Good start, but see comment below.

Comment: @FailSafe, basically, regex should find only the second story of the first example and totally ignore everything else. If that example exists, match it, and only that.

Comment: A test speaks volumes - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEgovMqGG_8 Indeed the regex does match both, but one group is staged inside of () meaning it will be returned, whereas the other is not meaning it will not be returned. See video

Comment: @FailSafe thanks a lot for your effort! I think I can pick it up from here. Good stuff indeed. I will accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Note also in place of `[\S\s]*?` you can use `.*` but I prefer not to because it causes so much confusion because `.` can match so many different things

Comment: @FailSafe if you could make it work here https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html (with this grammar https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) I would own you one. Ignore groups table, I only care about matches/not matches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190583/discussion-between-failsafe-and-darijan).

Comment: I moved our discussion to chat

Answer (score 1):

So to give a demonstration of kind of a dirty solution in Python, this should be able to do it

```
>>> string_1 = '''story(
  foo,
  stuff,
  bar,
)

story(
  stuff,
  bar,
)   '''




>>> string_2 = '''story(
  foo,
  stuff,
  bar,
)

story(
  foo,
  stupp,
  bar,
)'''





>>> def bad_file(string):
        import re
        matches = re.findall('story\([\S\s]*?foo[\S\s]*?bar[\S\s]*?\)|(story\([\S\s]*?bar[\S\s]*?\))', string)
        #matches = re.findall('story\([\S\s]*?foo[\S\s]*?bar[\S\s]*?\)|(story\([\S\s]*?\))', string)
        for i in range(len(matches)):
            if matches[i] != '':
                print('Bad File because of:\n')
                print(matches[i])
                print('\n'*2)
                print('List of bad matches:')
                return matches
            if i == (len(matches)) -1:
                print('Good File')


#Output
>>> bad_file(string_1)
Bad File


>>> bad_file(string_2)
Good File
```